# Spark Streaming from socket does not work with reduce operation

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, bigdata

I am trying to get a simple Spark-Streaming example working on my local machine.
I have a thread that writes As/Bs/Cs to a socket:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constants.PORT);
s1 = serverSocket.accept();
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));
    String character = alphabet.get(random.nextInt(alphabet.size())) ;
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());
    out.println(character);
    out.flush();
}
```

My main program, where I try to count the numbers of As/Bs/Cs looks as follows (without the reduce step):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // start socket writer thread
    System.setProperty("spark.cleaner.ttl", "10000");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(
            "local", 
            "Test",
            Constants.SPARK_HOME, 
            new String[]{"target/spark-standalone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
    Duration batchDuration = new Duration(TIME_WINDOW_MS);
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, batchDuration);
    JavaDStream<String> stream = streamingContext.socketTextStream("localhost", Constants.PORT);
    stream.print();
    JavaPairDStream<String, Long> texts = stream.map(new PairFunction<String, String, Long>() {

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Long> call(String t) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<String, Long>("batchCount" + t, 1l);
            }

        });
     texts.print();
     streamingContext.checkpoint("checkPointDir");
     streamingContext.start();
```

In this case everything works just fine (sample output for a batch):

```
Time: 1372413296000 ms
-------------------------------------------
B
A
B
C
C
C
A
B
C
C
...

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1372413296000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(batchCountB,1)
(batchCountA,1)
(batchCountB,1)
(batchCountC,1)
(batchCountC,1)
(batchCountC,1)
(batchCountA,1)
(batchCountB,1)
(batchCountC,1)
(batchCountC,1)
...
```

But if I add the reduction step after the map it does not work anymore. This code goes after texts.print()

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Long> reduced = texts.reduceByKeyAndWindow(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {

    @Override
    public Long call(Long t1, Long t2) throws Exception {
        return t1 + t2;
    }
    }, new Duration(TIME_WINDOW_MS));
reduced.print();
```

In this case I only get output for the first "stream" variable and "texts" variable and nothing for reduce. Also nothing happens after this first batch processing. I also set the spark log-level to DEBUG but did not encounter any exceptions or other strange things.

What happens here? Why do I get locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record: I got an answer in the Spark usergroup.
The error is that one has to use

```
"local[2]"
```

instead of

```
"local"
```

as a parameter to instantiate the Spark context, in order to enable concurrent processing.